# Slim framework put post from other server

Tags: php, slim

The code works fine on the same server.

My question is how can I do on one server and post the update?

So if I post on `www.domain1.com` to `www.domain2.com(api)` the `emailadres`, how can I achieve this? I am getting 404 page.

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->put('/user/update/:id/', function( $id ) use( $app ){
global $connection;
$app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");

if( $id && $id > 0 ){
    $result = $connection->query( 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = '.(int)$id.' ;' );
}else{
    $result = array();
}

if ($result) {
    $post = $app->request()->put();
    $result = $connection->query( "UPDATE `users` SET email = '".$_POST['email']."' WHERE id = $id;");
    echo json_encode(array(
    "status" => (bool)$result,
    "message" => "User updated successfully"
    ));
}
else{
    echo json_encode(array(
    "status" => false,
    "message" => "User id $id does not exist"
    ));
}
});

$app->run();?>
```

Form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="PUT"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Update user"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand well what you say. For me you have "www.domain1.com" where your users can access using html pages and "www.domain2.com" where you have your API. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($_POST){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://domain.com/user/update/7/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "email=".$_POST['email']."&_METHOD=put");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

Need to send _METHOD=put